# Buddy Press sort by last name?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, buddypress

I’ve been trying to get a Members Directory to sort by last name, but have had no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

The directory is here: http://109.199.101.20/~newfeldenkrais/practitioner-search/results/
The search is powered by the plugin BP Profile Search, but is displaying on the default members page.

Versions:
WP – Version 4.7.5
BP – Version 2.8.2
BP Profile Search – Version 4.7.6

I’ve tried various solutions that I was able to find on Google with no luck, the most recent solution I could find was here: https://buddypress.org/support/topic/custom-searchfilter-based-on-custom-field/

It looks like that solution is looking for the space between the First Name and Last Name to target the last name, but BuddyPress seems to be grabbing the “nicename”, which has no space. So, it isn’t able to target the space for me?

Answer (score 0):

Use this hook in functions.php,

```
public function alphabetize_by_last_name( $bp_user_query ) {
    if ( 'alphabetical' == $bp_user_query->query_vars['type'] )
        $bp_user_query->uid_clauses['orderby'] = "ORDER BY substring_index(u.display_name, ' ', -1)";
}
add_action ( 'bp_pre_user_query', 'alphabetize_by_last_name' );
```

Ref : https://gist.github.com/mgmartel/4463855 
https://buddypress.org/support/topic/sort-user-list-by-last-name/